# seg fault from 2d array allocation

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

i have a struct "cell" defined as

```
typedef struct{
int id;
terrainType terrain;
} cell;
```

i then make a 2d array of cells with

```
cell** makeCellGrid(int sizeX, int sizeY)
{  
    cell** theArray;  
    int i;

    theArray = (cell**) malloc(sizeX*sizeof(cell*));  

    for ( i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
    {
        theArray[i] = (cell*) malloc(sizeY*sizeof(cell));  
    }

   return theArray;  
}
```

at first i thought this was working fine but a few seg faults later i discovered that with some values (e.g. makeCellGrid(32, 87) ) it breaks.
im fairly fresh with C pointers and memory junk and was hoping some one could point me in the right direction here.

with lower number bounds i had no issue accessing it with

```
map[i][j].id = x;
```

and so on

EDIT: forgot to add, from testing, the seg fault originate from

```
theArray[i] = (cell*) malloc(sizeY*sizeof(cell));
```

Comment: This code seems fine. Are you sure you don't swap the X and Y indices by accident?

Comment: What are the values of `i` and `j`?

Comment: Are you on a system such as Linux where you can use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  If so, use it.  The code you show is not self-evidently the problem.  It is therefore likely related to how you are using the data that your code returns.

Comment: (1) **[Take out the casts on your malloc() calls.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)** (2) Ensure you're including `<stdlib.h>`. If the first `malloc()`'ed address dereference you experience dies like this appears to from your edit-comment, you may well not be storing a full pointer, which is more common than you think when you hide an implied `malloc()` function declaration with a cast such as this.

Comment: Why don't you just malloc x*y instead of allocating all structs separately? Malloc (and free) is very costly...

Comment: @DariuszWawer: Perhaps the y-vectors shall be used seperatly?

Comment: @alk possibly, but the function name suggests otherwise. It'll just be some kind of map used in a game. Moreover, using single memory block may improve code speed, because a large part of the map will always be loaded into cache, which wouldn't be possible for fragmented memory

Comment: @DariuszWawer: I do agree that the way to allocate memory should best follow its use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code lacks error checking for the `malloc()` system call.

So if the first call to `malloc()` failed the second one (in the loop) tries to assign memory to `NULL` which indeed leads to the segmentation violation your are witnessing.

You might consider modifing you code like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int id;
  TerrainType terrain;
} CellType;

void freeCellGrid(CellType ** ppCells, size_t sizeX)
{
  size_t i = 0;
  for (; i < sizeX; ++i)
  {
    free(ppCells[i]);
  }

  free(ppCells);
}

CellType ** makeCellGrid(size_t sizeX, size_t sizeY)
{  
    CellType ** ppCells = malloc(sizeX * sizeof(*ppCells));  

    if (ppCells)
    {
      size_t i = 0;

      for (; i < sizeX; ++i)
      {
          ppCells[i] = malloc(sizeY * sizeof(**ppCells));  
          if (NULL == ppCells[i])
          {
            freeCellGrid(ppCells, i);
            ppCells = NULL;

            break;
          }
      }
   }

   return ppCells;  
}
```

Notes on my modifications:

- Always check system calls for errors (in the case of `malloc()` on error `NULL` is returned)
- Better use an `unsigned` type to access memory/array indicies; `size_t` is meant for this
- In C there is no need to cast the value returned by a `void *` function like `malloc()`
- Always try to initialise variables as soon as possible; un-initilaised variables very easily lead to "irrational" behaviour of the application
- If working with pointers, it might be helpfull to 'code' the level of indirection into their names (I did this here by using the prefix `pp` to indicated that it's a 2-level indirection)
- types are different from variables: One way to distinguish this is by starting type names using capitals (`CellType`) and variables using small letters (`ppCells`).
- If allocating memory to a pointer and it matters that the size of the allocated memory some suits the pointer's type it's always more secure to use the (dereferenced) pointer itself as argument to the `sizeof` operator then some type. As the declaration of the pointer the memory is allocated to might be changed during develpment and the adjustment of the argument to `malloc()` will be forgotten. To cut it short: doing as I did is less error prone.
- If encapsulating the dynamical creation of structures (including arrays) it is a could idea to also implement a method which de-allocates it (here: `freeCellGrid()`). Even better start of with coding this deallocator first, as then you have it by hand when coding the allocator's error handling (as shown for the second call to `malloc()`).

Comment: Thanks. really great post with lots of usable info.